# sorting list of objects by attribute values, order of attribute values are in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

```
a = ['123b4', '234v5', 'lobf56']
b = [obj1, obj2, obj3] # where each obj is list of object which has attribute called 'serial' which matches serial numbers in list #a
```

Where obj1.serial is 234v5, obj2.serial is lobf56 and obj3.serial is 123b4

```
tmplist=list()
for each in a:
    for obj in b:
        if each == obj.serial:
            tmplist.append(obj)

print(tmplist)
```

output: [obj3, obj1, obj2]

I am currently able to achieve the sorting in above manner. But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) helps?

```
[obj for each in a for obj in b if each == obj.serial]
```

If you compare the time between both, your approach takes:

```
1.6 µs ± 25.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The list comprehension takes:

```
1.37 µs ± 18.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Therefore, if by "a better way to do it" you mean efficiency. This definitely counts.

Comment: What code *exactly* did you time? I'm just curious because the gap is usually not that big.

Comment: @Tomothy32, you are right. I made the mistake of including the print statement. I just updated my answer. Great catch!